# where is __null defined in g++?

Tags: null, g++

in g++, NULL is defined as __null, in 64-bit case, __null is 8 bytes. such as:

```
printf("sizeof(__null):%d, sizeof(0):%d\n", sizeof(__null), sizeof(0));
sizeof(__null):8, sizeof(0):4
```

however, where is __null defined?

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of `__null` is as a G++ internal. You won't find it in a header file or anything like that. You can find some explanation of the logic [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/support.html#std.support.types.null) but the basic idea is that it's the simplest way to ensure NULL is seen as a pointer first.

Basically, the internal does what you would naively expect `reinterpret_cast<void *>(0)` to do.

Comment: is there any way to detect the type of it?

Comment: Its type is 'magic', depending on context. That's the reason G++ had to implement it as an internal. No regular type provides the precisely-correct semantics. It acts roughly like 'void *', but not exactly.

Comment: Your link to "the logic" is now broken. BTW, in the context of `struct S{}s=__null;`, `__null` appears to behave as an `int`: the error emitted is "conversion from `int` to non-scalar type `S` requested".

Comment: It seems that the only magic thing about `__null` is that G++ ensures it has the same size as that of a pointer. In my test, I can see `__null` has the type `long` in 64-bit mode, and `int` in 32-bit mode.