# How is NULL defined in C++?

Tags: c++

In C, `NULL` is normally `#defined` as either `0` or `((void *)0)`. I expected this to be similar in C++, and many answers on stack overflow seem to suggest that's the case as well. However, when I try to compile the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int x) {
    printf("void *\n");
}

void f(void *x) {
    printf("int\n");
}

int main(void) {
    f(0);            // int
    f((void *)0);    // void *
    f(nullptr);      // void *
    f(NULL);         // why is this ambiguous?
    return 0;
}
```

I'm told by my compiler that `f(NULL)` is ambiguous. Specifically, my compiler says:

```
sample.cpp:15:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(NULL);
    ^
sample.cpp:3:6: note: candidate function
void f(void *x) {
     ^
sample.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function
void f(int x) {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

If `NULL` was defined as either `0` or `((void *)0)`, I'd expect it to resolve to the `int` overload or the `void *` overload of `f`, but it doesn't. If `NULL` was defined to be `nullptr` for some reason, that would also resolve to the `void *` overload. What gives?

I compiled on a Mac with `g++ --std=c++11 sample.cpp` for anyone trying to replicate this. Haven't tried it on other platforms.

For an example of an answer that talks about `NULL` in C++, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c).

EDIT: I know to always use `nullptr` over `NULL` when possible in C++. This question came up when I tried to come up with a few examples of why to show someone.

Comment: compile with `-E` to see what the preprocessor is doing.

Comment: apparently `NULL` is defined as `__null` @RyanHaining

Comment: Prefer using `nullptr` over `NULL`, *always*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I do whenever I have C++11 or greater, which unfortunately is not often. I was just trying to demonstrate why `NULL` was dangerous and ended up with this mess, which I guess makes a pretty good case for using `nullptr`.

Comment: I don't know anything more about this, but dug to https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/c06fed002f4859ab3eaab5401d7d48a75ffecd89/include/clang-c/Index.h#L2031

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso If you wanna get ahead of all the "use nullptr" comments (or similar on other questions) you're gonna have to call it out really obviously in the question that you already know that.

Comment: @RyanHaining I've edited, hopefully that's enough lol.  This answer seems to cover what `__null` is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783566/where-is-null-defined-in-g

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) since C++11 :

> an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`

On your platform, it seems if you add a `long int` overload it resolves the ambiguity. I therefore assume that `NULL` on your platform with those flags is a `long int` with the value 0, or `0l` : [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/lZ-_vZ). I don't know why they chose `0l` over just `0`, but it is an integer literal with the value zero, so it seems like that's allowed.

This means that the result of this program depends on your compiler and your compilation flags, so beware. The use of `nullptr` is preferred.

Comment: yup, I'm aware that `nullptr` is preferred, was just trying to show someone why and ended up with these compile time errors. This explains it though.

Comment: I think you mean `0l`, not `l0`. I didn't realize the standard allowed that, wow.