# Does clang support __null?

Tags: c++, c++14, clang++, llvm-clang

When I am compiling the following program with clang++ version 5.0, it is resulting in

> error: initializer on function does not look like a pure-specifier

```
extern void print(void *ptr);

#define NULL __null

class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual void method1() = NULL;
};


int main()
{
    void *ptr = NULL;
    print(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems `__null` is not supported by clang? But some posts in stackoverflow suggests clang supports `__null`. If so why am I getting this error. Could somebody suggest whats going on here?

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/-f3Kf9

Comment: are you pre c++11? If not, why not use `nullptr`? If yes, better add the appropriate tag

Comment: It is a g++ wart, C++ requires `=0` here.

Comment: Just use `nullptr` everywhere already. Don't use`__null`, `0` or `NULL` *anywhere* - use *`nullptr`* for null pointer constants. But, for declaring a pure vertical function, the syntax is `= 0` so there, that's what you *have* to use.

Answer (score 10):

The syntax for pure virtual function is only `= 0`. For example, `virtual void do_stuff() = 0` is allowed, but `virtual void do_stuff() = nullptr` is not allowed.

Clang does support `__null` but that compiler internal is not meant to declare virtual functions.

The only reason that `NULL` *might* work for pure virtual functions is that some system define it as `0`, but you should not rely on that. Some compiler might also use `0LL` or `(void*)0`.

If you can, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for declaring null pointers. This is the best solution and can be emulated in older standards.

For declaring pure virtual functions, use `= 0`. This is the simplest and the usual way to declare pure virtual functions.

Comment: Might need a little rewording; right now the first paragraph appears to contradict with the last paragraph, until you look closer

Comment: @Lightness... Thank you... So __null is keyword? Its not macro? where can I see its definition?

Comment: It's not really a keyword, but a compiler internal. You can usually recognise those with the leading double undescore.

Comment: @Pendyala Apparently [it's an implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8783589/560648) (that answer is about GCC but Clang has some similar things), so... neither really. It certainly isn't standard. I have no idea why you chose to use it.

Comment: [By the Holy Laws of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), anything that contains two underscores in a row is an implementation detail that is not portable and may vanish any time you upgrade your tools. That or it's a potential programming mistake that can result in very confusing errors or runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be some sort of misunderstanding here. Making a virtual function pure is not the same thing as initializing it to a null pointer. In fact, some compilers will set the vtable entry for a pure function to point to a special function called `__cxa_pure_virtual` or something like that.

Since you are not actually initializing a pointer, you can't use `__null` here. [Not even GCC 4.1 allows it.](https://godbolt.org/z/8Bw-D1) Nor can you use `nullptr`, which is the standard replacement for `__null`. Just write `= 0;` here.

Comment: This is a good example of why I think the whole `= 0` thing is misleading. I realise the timeline's wrong for it, but a `[[pure]]` attribute would have been much better. (Or perhaps some other name)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I agree. That being said, in the grand scheme of bad C++ design decisions, this hardly deserves a footnote.

Comment: Indeed that is so!

Answer (score 2):

What is going on here is:

1. For some reason, you're using a compiler internal (`__null`) instead of the standard `nullptr` (at worst, the old `NULL` was already in the standard and did not need defining by you)
2. For some reason, you're trying to use `__null` (or `NULL` (or `nullptr`)) as a *pure virtual function specifier*. You can't do that. It's supposed to be `= 0`. I believe GCC permits, or used to permit, what you're doing as an extension; Clang doesn't.

Simple as that really!

Your next steps:

1. Stop using `__null` for null pointers; use `nullptr` instead.
2. Stop using null pointers for pure virtual function specifiers. It's `= 0`.