# Does any major C++ implementation actually define `NULL` as `nullptr`?

Tags: c++, c++11, null, std, nullptr

Since C++11, the Standard allows the macro `NULL` to either be a integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Any Standard Library vendor deciding to change their definition of `NULL` from an integer to `nullptr` would very likely cause breakage for clients relying on pre-C++11 code.

**Does any major implementation (e.g. GCC, Clang, MSVC) actually define `NULL` as `nullptr`?** Or, despite the possibility, does nobody do this?

Comment: You can trivially determine this for your toolchain (indeed, for all three). Are you experiencing some practical problem with obtaining this information?

Comment: Also, why does it matter?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: no, I figured that it would be more valuable to have the information publicly available as a StackOverflow question, which can be found from people with the same curiosity in the future without requiring duplicated work. I also figured that there might be some "non-major" implementation that I am not aware of which might do something different, and someone might want to share their information on that.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: you're also assuming that I am not doing the research as we speak (I am), but I preferred writing the question first to see if somebody had already done the work. If nobody replies, I will self-answer.

Comment: I think there is a certain subjectivity in what folks may consider a 'major implementation'.

Comment: I see. Perhaps we have different definitions of the word "valuable". :)

Comment: If changing `NULL` from `0L` to `nullptr` breaks your code, your code has always been broken imho.

Comment: @Ayxan Not when the definition is shared with C implementations, as it almost always is. I can think of very little reason any project would want to go to the trouble of making `NULL` mean `nullptr` in C++.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: do you know a case where it isn't shared with C implementations? I am interested in that.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I do not - by saying "almost" I was just hedging my bets ;)

Comment: @Ayxan For what it's worth, "your code was broken anyway" might be true in principle, but in practice implementers will still try not to cause headaches for no good reason, no matter whose "fault" it is.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings what do you mean by "Shared with C"? It's usually `0L` for C++ and `(void*)0` for C with `#ifndef __cplusplus`.

Comment: @Ayxan Ah, really? Did not know that.

Comment: Regardless, this has turned into a discussion without revealing why this information is valuable or why it should be sought in an SO question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: are curiosities about a language explicitly disallowed on SO? If you want some *"value"*, then knowing whether my C++03 code with improper usage of `NULL` will work on any major implementation is indeed valuable if I am thinking of migrating.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: a more *valuable* use of your time would be not interacting with a question you're not interested in, but do not assume that everybody feels the same way.

Comment: @Asteroids - Major implementations already went to the trouble of differentiating `NULL` between C and C++ in the past (`(void*)0` in C vs just `0` in C++). It isn't a stretch.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Do the reasons they went to that trouble apply to this hypothetical too? I am getting the impression that they "had to" make the prior distinction, whereas there's no good reason to make a change here now?

Comment: @Asteroids - Obtaining a synonym for a valid null pointer constant that is as least error prone as possible? Certainly. Otherwise a plain 0 would have sufficed for C as well.

Comment: For reference, STL had an anecdote about trying to change this and running into a bunch of problems within their own code: https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4?t=3437. OTOH, there was [this tweet](https://twitter.com/stephantlavavej/status/1000548957171273728) some years later, same person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libstdc++` [relies on including `stddef.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/c/cstddef#L34-L38), which defines `NULL` in the following way:

```
// <stddef.h>
//
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define NULL __null
#else   /* G++ */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
#endif  /* G++ */
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
#undef  __need_NULL
```

Information about `__null` can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783566/where-is-null-defined-in-g):

> The implementation of `__null` is as a G++ internal. Basically, the internal does what you would naively expect `reinterpret_cast<void *>(0)` to do.
>
> Its type is 'magic', depending on context. That's the reason G++ had to implement it as an internal. No regular type provides the precisely-correct semantics. It acts roughly like `void *`, but not exactly.

---

`libc++` [does pretty much the same thing](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/cstddef#L43-L45):

```
// <cstddef>
//
// Don't include our own <stddef.h>; we don't want to declare ::nullptr_t.
#include_next <stddef.h>
#include <__nullptr>
```

---

Microsoft's `STL` also [relies on including `stddef.h`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/cstddef#L12):

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _CSTDDEF_
#define _CSTDDEF_
#include <yvals_core.h>
#if _STL_COMPILER_PREPROCESSOR

#include <stddef.h>
```

I could not find `stddef.h` in the open-source STL repository, but a definition of `NULL` is provided in `vcruntime.h`:

```
#ifndef NULL
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define NULL 0
    #else
        #define NULL ((void *)0)
    #endif
#endif
```

---

A simple test on `icc 19.0.1` also shows that `NULL` is not defined as `nullptr`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(NULL), std::nullptr_t>::value, "");
static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype(NULL), int>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(NULL), long>::value, "");
```

[**live on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MQ55aQ)