# NULL behaviour on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was trying [this](https://godbolt.org/z/sYda3re8e) code snippet

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

void f(int* ptr){
    std::printf("int*\n");
}

void f(int val){
    std::printf("int\n");
}

int main() {
    f(NULL);
}
```

This errors out on both GCC and CLANG but MSVC prints `int`. As per my reading of [`[conv.ptr]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.ptr), since a null pointer constant (which is what [`NULL`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.types.nullptr#2) is) of *integral type* can be converted to a pointer type, it should be ambiguous for the compiler while selecting the appropriate function since it can bind both to `int` and `int*`. I confirmed that all these compilers have `NULL` implemented as an integral type via

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(NULL), int>(), "");
#else
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(NULL), long>(), "");
#endif
```

So, is this an MSVC bug or am I missing something and compilers are not expected to throw an error in such cases?

EDIT: I'm aware that `nullptr` is *the* way to gauge null-ness, but this question is merely out of curiosity and an attempt at understanding the specification around it.

Comment: Not sure about gcc and clang, but MSVC has `#define NULL 0`, so it's a simple int type which explains your result. Do you think MSVC does not conform with the standard ?

Comment: Stop using `NULL` and instead use [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: It all depends on how the implementation defines `NULL` _"...The macro NULL is an __implementation-defined__ null pointer constant, which may be..."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL  Some implementations will use `0` some will use `std::nullptr_t`  And then we have to look at how many implicit conversions are allowed when doing overload resolution.

Comment: One platform I worked on used `#define NULL __null`, and the `__null` was compiler magic (I think for generating warnings, which had to be opt-in enabled).

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8783566), it looks like GCC decided to always ensure `NULL` is defined as `__null` despite this being a non-portable thing. They are allowed to do this as mentioned in comments above. So strictly speaking this failure of resolution is perfectly legal because GCC doesn't actually define a type for `__null` other than "pointer width" as best I can tell.

Answer (score 6):

[`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is an old C-compatibility macro. It's usually defined as the plain integer `0`. Because of that `f(int)` will be called.

In C++ you should be using [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) for null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> since a null pointer constant (which is what NULL is) of integral type can be converted to a pointer type, it should be ambiguous for the compiler while selecting the appropriate function since it can bind both to int and int*.

It's only ambiguous when the overload resolution has to choose between two equivalent conversion sequences. E.g. from `0L` to `int` or `int*`.

But overload resolution is trivial when one of the overloads is a perfect match. And as it happens, `0` is a perfect match for `int`.

Both `0` and `0L` have integral type, so all compilers are correct.

Bonus:

```
void f(std::integral auto val) {
    std::printf("integral\n");
}
```

Perfect match after template instantiation.